# ZSH: tab complete file in subdirectory by name

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I would like to be able to type a filename in zsh, hit tab, and see a list of files that match that name in any subdirectories of my current directory. Then I could tab through those results and hit enter to select a certain file, just like the built-in zsh tab completion functionality works.

Example desired functionality:

```
$ emacs app.css [tab]
*www/css/app.css*    tmp/static/app.css
[enter]
$ emacs www/css/app.css
```

If this is not currently a feature, I assume I could write a custom completion script to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve something similar by utilizing the `**` pattern (match over multiple directories) and by adding the control function `_expand` to the `completer` style (if not already the case).

As a minimum, you need to make the following settings:

```
autoload -U compinit
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand
compinit
```

Then you can get the desired list with

```
% emacs **/app.css[TAB]
```

It even allows for the option to open all matching files at once.

Comment: I really like this solution but when I put it in my .zshrc file it prevents the standard tab complete from working. Where do I need to put this so I can make it work with standard tab complete? I'm using zsh-autosuggestions, I am a software dev but I've not done shell scripting before.

Comment: From what I can see, it should not interfere with zsh-autosuggestions. But if `compinit` is already configured and loaded in your `~/.zshrc`, then just adding this as it is might disable some settings. Check, if you already have any of these lines in your configuration, in which case you can just add `_expand` to the list of arguments after `completer`. For example, I have `zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand _complete _approximate` in my own configuration. If you do not have these lines (especially `compinit`), you might not be using the "new" (since 2000) completion system.